# Custom command with nested get() inside get().within() return wrong data

Tags: javascript, cypress

After the update, Cypress to version 5.4 custom commands returns the wrong data. Before the update, this custom command return array of `tr`, but now, it returns the whole table element, like only first `get()` work and returns a value. What more interesting, inside a second callback, inside `.within()`, the value inside is proper, but the whole command returns something else.

```
// Works in 4.7 but not in 5.4

Cypress.Commands.add('getTableColumnValues', (selector) => {
    cy.get(selector).within(() => {
        cy.get('tbody tr').then((rows) => {
            // here rows is correct array of tr
            return rows;
        });
    });
});
```

```
// Usage

cy.getGridColumnValues('.custom-table').then((values) => {
    // Expected value: array of tr
    // Actual result: array with 1 element - table.custom-table
});
```

```
// Works fine

Cypress.Commands.add('getTableColumnValues', (selector) => {
    cy.get(`${selector} tbody tr`).then((rows) => {
        return rows;
    });
});
```

Can somebody help me understand why this works like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were changes that were made for `within()` in the version 5.4.0. Its mentioned in their [changelog](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#5-4-0) under bugfixes:

[image: cypress 5.4.0 changelog bugfix]

Comment: Thanks, this is the source of my problem. Cypress [PR](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/8699) with that change.

Answer (score 2):

See [docs - .within(): Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Yields)

> .within() yields the same subject it was given from the previous command

The behavior isn't consistent with [docs - .then(): Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Yields)

> Whatever is returned from the callback function becomes the new subject and will flow into the next command

but

> When undefined is returned by the callback function (i.e no return statement), the subject will not be modified and will instead carry over to the next command.

So, IMO they should apply the same pattern to `.within()` and allow an explict `return` to change the subject.

---

You can adapt the custom command by adding a `.then()` which changes the subject

Here's a [cypress fiddle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/fiddle)

```
// loads TypeScript definition for Cypress
// and "cy.runExample" custom command
/// <reference types="@cypress/fiddle" />

Cypress.Commands.add('getTableColumnValues', (selector) => {
  let result;
  cy.get(selector).within(() => {
      cy.get('tbody tr').then((rows) => {
          // here rows is correct array of tr
          result = rows;
      });
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(result)
    return result
  })
});

const withinTest = {
  html: `
    <table class="custom-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
  test: `
    cy.getTableColumnValues('.custom-table').then((values) => {
      // values = array of tr
      console.log(values)
    });
  `
}

it('tests within() returning a new subject', () => {
  cy.runExample(withinTest)
})
```

Comment: The use of `return` to allow the user to control behavior of the `.within()` command has been proposed [Using .within() in custom commands/functions to return an inner DOM element found in .within() results](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8873#issuecomment-720908999)